# How to create a Unix Domain socket?

Tags: perl, sockets

I am trying to learn how to use sockets to communicate between processes on the same machine. I started with this simple test program taken from Perl Cookbook:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;

my $socket_file = 'mysocket';
if ( -e $socket_file ) {
    unlink $socket_file or die "Could not delete socket file '$socket_file': $!";
}
my $sock = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    LocalAddr => $socket_file,
    Type      => SOCK_STREAM,
    Listen    => 5, # listen to max 5 connections
) or die "Could not create socket: '$@'";

say "Created socket successfully..";
sleep 1;
close $sock;
say "Closed socket..";

exit;
```

The output is:

```
Could not create socket: '' at ./test.pl line 10.
```

So the question is: Why does `IO::Socket::UNIX->new()` fail, and why does it not set `$@` when it fails?

Comment: Seems to work if I change `LocalAddr` to `Local`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't set `$@` because `IO::Socket::UNIX` doesn't use `eval` anywhere.
If you print out `$!` instead of `$@`, you might see:

```
Invalid argument at xxx.pl line 10.
```

At which point you may consult the [`IO::Socket::UNIX` docs](http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::UNIX) and see that the correct parameter to pass is `Local` and not `LocalAddr`.

Comment: The Perl Cookbook dates to 1998 and I have no idea how `IO::Socket::UNIX` worked back then.

Comment: Yes seems like the information in the book is not very accurate. Are there any newer resources? If I add a client ( a new program) that will write to the same socket should I then use `Peer` and `Timeout` instead of `Listen` and `Local` as is used by the server?

Comment: I don't know anything good except [`IO::Socket`](http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket) and ['perlipc`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlipc). These have also been around for a long time but they are occasionally refreshed with up-to-date examples.